# How to handle NullPointerException in android while using intents in listview?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

My layout consists of an edittext and listview.On clicking a listitem it should launch a new activity which should display the string entered by the user in edittext.
This is my launch activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 

{

String []fonts=new String[]{"Droid Serif","Droid Sans","Droid Sans Mono"};

ListView lv;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

EditText e;

String msg;

String a=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fonts);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    msg=e.getText().toString();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Final.class);
                if(msg.equals(a)) {
                    i.putExtra("msg", msg);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NullPointerException("no null");
                }


        }});

}
}
```

This is my second activity.

```
public class Final extends Activity {

TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String msg=getIntent().getExtras().getString("msg",null);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hello);
    t.setText(msg);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to set the text entered by the user in edittext.When i run this app i get a new activity with a blank layout.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If it did, please accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

`TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);`

after:

`setContentView(R.layout.hello);`

You are getting an NPE because you are trying to initialize your `TextView t` before your activity has been created. the method `findViewById(int)` is a method of the activity itself, and cannot be executed until the activity is instantiated in `onCreate()`.

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) is an excellent article to give you some insight into how the activity lifecycle works. I would highly recommend spending some more time reading up on activities and the basics of them before moving forward with Android, especially the lifecycle. In addition, when you post questions in the future, I would highly recommend trying to be a little more clear, posting the error logs, and telling us what you have already tried that has not worked.